# Stored procedure in Azure database runs fast in ASP.NET but slow in SSMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, ssms

I have an Azure database with S0 pricing tier. When I run the stored procedure, it takes about 20 seconds to display the result both in my ASP.NET website and SSMS.

Now, I downgraded pricing tier to Basic. When I run the same stored procedure, it shows message timeout in ASP.NET website. When I execute the stored procedure in SSMS, it takes about 35 seconds.

I analyze my database. From the actual execution plan tab, it suggests to create an index. I follow the suggestion. I create some index in my table.

The result, in my ASP.NET website only takes about 1-2 seconds to show the result. But in SSMS, the loading time not change. It also takes 35 seconds.

I already closed SSMS and reconnect Azure database again but it does not change the loading time. My SSMS is SSMS 2016 (version 13.0.16106.4)

What happens with my Azure database?

Comment: My first guess is that for whatever reason the SSMS query is still using the old execution plan and not taking advantage of the new index. You can use sp_recompile to try and force the system to recompile the execution plan for that stored proc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-recompile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT I already test sp_recompile but not change

Answer (score 0):

Today, after I try the stored procedure again, the result surprise me. Both in SSMS and ASP.NET website, it takes a long time. In ASP.NET website I get a timeout page. In SSMS, it takes about 30-35 seconds to show data. I am very confused with Azure. So, now my problem is this stored procedure slow to select data.

So, I cross check my stored procedure. I change format of my stored procedure, run the select command with direct write the value, remove the parameter, etc. The result, the stored procedure now only take 1-2 sec to load data.

Below, I write some summary base on my experience:

1. If your stored procedure uses some `FORMAT` in select statement and if your stored procedure has a `DATE` parameter, it will be very slow.
2. Don't use too many `FORMAT` in `SELECT` statement. If you want to format the value, do it in ASP.NET or C#.
3. Change `FORMAT` to `CONVERT` because in my experience, `FORMAT` drags performance down.

This is the code i changed and than it boost my stored procedure performance:

Before

```
FORMAT(b.tglTransaksi,'dd-MM-yy','en-US') AS [Tanggal],
FORMAT((a.upTime+'07:00'),'HH:mm:ss','en-US') AS [Waktu Input],
FORMAT(a.idMaster,'0000000#','en-US') AS [No. Ref],
```

After

```
CONVERT(CHAR(8),b.tglTransaksi,5) AS [Tanggal],
CONVERT(CHAR(8),a.upTime+'07:00',108) AS [Waktu Input],
RIGHT('00000000'+CAST(a.idMaster AS VARCHAR(8)),8) AS [No. Ref],
```

With this command `SELECT @@VERSION;`, my Azure version is

```
 Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   May  2 2019 20:11:13   
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
```

I use the basic pricing tier (5 DTU).

Perhaps this experience can help others.

Comment: Changing the code most likely just forced a new (better) plan to be generated. For completion, why don't you try changing back to `FORMAT` now and see if stays fast

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I already change back to FORMAT. It load slow again. Maybe if tomorrow or next time FORMAT can fast or CONVERT become slow, i will update this post again